# Plotting varImp in R

Tags: r

Im using the varImp function of the caret package and Im trying to plot the resulting dataframe that it creates. Here is the code:

```
RocImp2 <- varImp(svmFit, scale = FALSE)
```

and Im using a simple plot to plot the chart:

```
plot(RocImp2)
```

The results are supposed to look like this:

[image]

whereas mine looks like this:

[image]

Here is a copy of the dataframe:

[image]

disregard the names in the plot as they are from another example.

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include all data and code necessary to reproducible the plot. Do not include images of data, include actual data.

Comment: Use dotplot or varImpPlot {randomForest}?

Answer (score 5):

My issue was fixed by adding the following.

`ggplot2::ggplot(varImp())`

Answer (score 3):

here is a solution to plot the varImp in the case of a binary classification model.

`model = glm(Survived~.,family="binomial", data=Titanic)`

```
V = caret::varImp(model)

ggplot2::ggplot(V, aes(x=reorder(rownames(V),Overall), y=Overall)) +
geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6)+
geom_segment( aes(x=rownames(V), xend=rownames(V), y=0, yend=Overall), 
color='skyblue') +
xlab('Variable')+
ylab('Overall Importance')+
theme_light() +
coord_flip()
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround this problem. You could try:

```
write.csv(RocImp2, file = 'RocImp2.csv')

VIMP <- read.csv('RocImp2.csv')

plot(VIMP)
```